# pydrive on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

i tried to run this code on my raspberry pi to be able to send file on my google drive from my raspberry pi i put  the client_secret.json file in the same directory and i tried the same thing on my pc and everything run find put on the raspberry i get this error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'GoogleAuth' from 'pydrive.auth' (/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py)
```

the code that i was running is

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
```

and pydrive is install

Answer (score 0):

The docs [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/quickstart.html#authentication) say that you need to name your json file 'clients_secret.json' not 'secret_client.json' but I'm not sure if that's the issue. How have you installed the pydrive library? Was it using pip?

Comment: my bad the file is actually name ''client_secret.json'' yes the pydrive library is installed and it was via pip

Comment: Have you got multiple versions of python installed? Sometimes instead of running `pip install pydrive` you have to run `pip3 install pydrive`, in the case that you're defaulting to the use of Python 3